# Playstore on Nexus_5x_API_25 system image

Tags: android, emulation

I want to install playstore on my emulator. I know that there are a lot of workarounds using gapps but after some research I've found following link:
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/android-studio-24-preview-4-is-now.html
However I havent't found any system image with playstore installed, only those with the google-apis. Is there a solution to this problem other than using opengapps?

Edit: In my opinion it seems like on the official android studion nexus_5 emulators playstore is installed/supported but there is no image including it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: donot use gapp, you will not be able to run your app from android studio it will give you some wired error, as in your pic the google services will be able you can use maps etc.. or use bluestack it will have google play store install in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, the Google Play store app is only installed on API 24 and API 26 emulator system images. API 25 should come out shortly. As your link indicates, choose a Nexus 5 or Nexus 5x screen size and then select one of the "Google Play" system images as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Android Studio 3.0 AVD Manager]

I recommend using the AVD Manager in Android Studio 2.4 or 3.0 so that you can properly see all the options.  The end result should be the Play Store in the emulator system image and a new updated control panel on the Android Emulator settings page as discussed on this official blog post: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for. For some reason I haven't seen the images :D .  Anyway, I can't modify it's emualtor settings like ram at all, but it doesn't really matter as it runs smoothly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well  i don't know the emulator you are using and also since you said that you don't want to use gapps alternatives well i'm going to drop a list of sites that i think could be of help. just try and check them out and http://opengapps.org/ or https://medium.com/@dai_shi/installing-google-play-services-on-an-android-studio-emulator-fffceb2c28a1 it seems like a lot but i'm pretty sure that one of these links might solve your problem.

Comment: I'm using the android studio emulators (Nexus_5 is marked as playstore supporting)

Comment: Did you try signing in with your google account on the emulator. If you tried that and it didn't work out try the solution on this link. It sure should help https://medium.com/@dai_shi/installing-google-play-services-on-an-android-studio-emulator-fffceb2c28a1